# Same tab Command Line flag for Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

Google chrome has command line flag for new Window i.e. chrome.exe --new-window .

User Scenario is , while browsing we usually see chrome open certain hyperlink into same tab & for some it actually creates a new tab .

My thinking is , there must be some command line option or a flag which directs this navigation to same tab or new tab.

In my workaround , I looked at https://src.chromium.org/svn/trunk/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc to see if any flag available for it or not.

I am looking for Same tab command line flag or option. Suggestions , comments will be a great help.

Along with that , Can Chrome Extension could help me with this Same Tab Navigation ?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't think there are any command line flag for this feature since there can be privacy/security risk and malicious hackers try to exploit it.

Comment: But if you know chrome extension this can be coded to open in a particular tab from a background script... I've done it on a chrome ext before, but its not for the same use case as yours, it doesn't and cant be called from command line